# C# HTTP Send Async Error 405

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am writing a program using c# and API.NET to connect to an API in a separate system and the first step is to request an access token and I'm already stuck. I'm no wiz at C# yet so I'm sure I'm missing something. What is supposed to happen is the code takes the client id and secret, encodes it with base 64 then sends the code to the server to request the token. Please see below code and let me know if you see anything wrong. The error I'm getting is 
**"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while sending the request."**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace HSD_AIM.API.Controllers
{
    public class SchoolsController : ApiController
    {
         public async Task<string> Get()
         {
             string URL = @"https://ps.helenaschools.org/";
             string clientId = "myClientID";
             string clientSecret = "myClientSecret";
             string ret ="";

             string credential = Base64Encode($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}");
             using(var client = new HttpClient())
             {
                 client.BaseAddress=new Uri(Url);
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorizaiton", $"Basic {credential}");
                 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "oauth/Access_token/");
                 var requestContent = "grant_type=client_credentials";
                 request.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "applicaion/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                 var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                 {
                     ret = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    public static string Base64Encode(string text)
    {
        var textBytes = Encoding.ETF8.GetBytes(text);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(textBytes);
    }
}
```

I'm coding in VS2017 Community and running my API through the debugger. I can access the data from the API I am trying to talk to using the Advanced REST Client.

Comment: Look at the InnerException, there should be more useful info.

Comment: Next time post your Request code.  But chances are you are sending a Post Method instead of a get (Since you're receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed)

Comment: `Authorizaiton`? Did you mean `Authorization`? Also, `applicaion` should have been `application`

Comment: Are you hitting your controller? Or your getting this from the HTTPClient, if its from the HttpClient it sound like @CamiloTerevinto answer is correct.  But to add on top of that Why aren't you using Middleware to Authenticate instead,

Comment: @johnny5 Not sure about your comment about using Middleware. Care to explain? As for the post method, that is the way that it has to be to authenticate with the service I'm authenticating to.